# How to add cast to camera in android

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

Update**
full class:

```
public class TorchActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton btnSwitch;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // flash switch button
    btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);

    ...

    ...

    // get the camera
    getCamera();

    ...
    // Switch button click event to toggle flash on/off
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        ...
    });
}


// Get the camera
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(); //The method open() is undefined for the type Camera
            params = camera.getParameters();  //Add cast to 'camera'
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

here iam creating a flashlight application, which simply access the flash permission through the camera application.
i am unable to provide cast to 'camera'...
how can i do so?

SLOUTION:

these error are caused by the use of `Import.android.graphics.camera` instead of `Import.android.hardware.camera` after using right import there are no errors whatsoever.

Comment: What type does `params` have?

Comment: Please post your full class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Camera theCamera = camera;
    if (theCamera == null) {
        theCamera = Camera.open();
        if (theCamera == null) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        camera = theCamera;
    }
```

Try opening camera that way. If you get exception  - you can't use camera(probably camera was already opened & not closed). Else you may use it as you wish

**EDIT**
Seems that your problem is another:
Your import should be [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) (android.hardware.Camera), but NOT [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) (android.graphics.Camera)
Check it

Comment: it is still giving the same error at `open();`
i.e, `The method open() is undefined for the type Camera`

Comment: you don't say Sam N-a ?

Comment: I added my answer. I thought it's straightforward even without direct telling what to change =)

Answer (score 0):

these error are caused by the use of  `Import.android.graphics.camera` instead of `Import.android.hardware.camera`
after using right import there are no errors whatsoever.